# Is there any way to provide global classes to material-ui component in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I have some global classes for fonts and colors, but cannot use these classes in material-ui Typography. used library for material ui : https://material-ui.com/

in below code:

```
<Typography className={'font14 contrastText'} color="primary" gutterBottom>
    Sell your old {newLine} device
</Typography>
```

property of classes `font14` and `contrastText` is not applying on `p` tag which is generated by `Typography` tag.

Comment: className should be applied, provide a reproducable example.

Comment: Hi @Vaibhav Vishal, In sample project on `stackblitz` it's working fine, but in my code `MuiTypography` theming overriding my css.  don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [createMuiTheme](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/#api) function to override the default theme.

By providing a custom theme, you can change anything globally:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
      primary: purple,
      secondary: green,
  },
});
```

Pass that into your provider:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
```

This will let you use the colors like you do it above:

```
<Typography color="primary" gutterBottom>
       Sell your old {newLine} device
</Typography>
```

The color will now be purple for the text.
You can use the same for fonts for example.

If you just want to override one local propriety, you have to pass the className with the classes prop:

```
<Typography classes={{root: 'font14 contrastText'}} color="primary" gutterBottom>
       Sell your old {newLine} device
</Typography>
```

This will apply the classNames to your root component and will work as desired as well.

To override it locally, you have to increase the [specificity](https://specifishity.com). Use an id for example to override the material-ui classes.

Comment: it add class `MuiTypography-body1` to dom element, so cannot override font-size property.

Comment: Do you want to change it globally or just this case?

Comment: want to change only for this component.